# How many shrines are there?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

How many shrines are there, and if I want to go hunt down some I might have missed, is there any indicator in what region there might be an unexplored shrines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [IGN Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Shrines), there are **120 Shrines**.

I'm not sure if there are any indicators saying if you missed one in a region (if there is a stats menu, I would check there), but IGN also has an interactive map that you can filter on to show just the Shrines.  You can find the map [here](http://www.ign.com/maps/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/hyrule).

Comment: By the way, you can check the number of shrines you completed in the loading screen. Below the hearts and the stamina vessels there is an icon indicating that looks a little like a gemstone with the number of  shrines you completed.

Comment: I believe the Champion's Ballad DLC adds 13 shrines.

Comment: @JoshB. 12 if you don't count the Maz Koshia Shrine. I'd actually say it doesn't count, because if you count it you might just as well count the Divine Beasts.

Comment: I just recently completed all of the shrines, and it appears that the one hit obliterator shrines count as spirit orb shrines, so you can get 124 spirit orbs, with a total of 124 shrines with spirit orbs, 12 shrines for the songs of the champions (3 for each champion), and 5 divine beasts.