# Is there any way to view the completion percentage of the game?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the Easy Allies review, they talk that they did about 30% completion of the game.

Is there a way in the game to find out completion percentage or are they eyeballing it?

Comment: Since the game can be boiled down into korok seeds, shrines, and quests, they could just be eyeballing it. I don't know of any completion % on any screen anywhere.

Comment: You can only view the completion % after beating ganon once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Completion Rate, via the Official Zelda Guide]
According to the Official Guide, the completion rate is shown on the lower-left corner on the Sheikah Slate's map, and adds up by .08% for every "relevant objective", which could be tasks such as;

- Finding 1 of the 900 Korok seeds
- Completing 1 of the 100 shrines
- Defeating one of the bosses
- Discovering a new location

Hope this helped!

Comment: Are you sure about the numbers? 100 shrines doesn't sound right. See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302514/how-many-shrines-are-there

Comment: @TiffymoAcorn There are 120 Shrines in game, as answered here https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302514/how-many-shrines-are-there

Answer (score 6):

Once you have defeated Ganon and thus completed the main quest for the game, your saved games will be indicated with a star to show that you have completed the game. This will also reveal the % completion on your world map.

Things like treasure chests and adding things to the compendium does not count towards this %. As already mentioned, only specific things counts, and they all weight in the same, which is slightly more than 0.08% (no, it's not 0.08% and neither is it 0.09%, it is some unknown number, but approximately 0.081%, which is why it sometimes seems to add 0.09%).

It should also be mentioned that completing shrines yields you 0%. Finding the shrine and activating it, however, yields progress towards completion. I find that wierd, but that is how it works.